# Detect if payment has been placed in sales_order_save_after observer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

I have a custom extension that uses `sales_order_save_after` basically i want to create an invoice after the customer put a payment data , the problem is the order seems not been created at so i got an error like this:

```
Call to a member function getAdditionalInformation() on null in vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php:172
```

then i remove the create invoice function from my observer, then it does not got any error.

After i successfully place an order , i try this create invoice function again using the success order , the create invoice function run smoothly.

It seems the function is triggered before the payment has been placed, is there a way to detect if the payment has been placed using this observer or order?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

It will help you with the solution.